# How can I bind Width of another element in Angular 2 - HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, size

I have an input and a table.

```
<input type="search"/>
<table id="myTable"/>
```

How can I bind the width of my input to the same width of the table?

Something like this?

```
<input type="search" [style.width]="#myTable.width"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reference in input tag should be for the `<table>`'s template variable, not the id. `#` is not necessary when using it in the expressions. You also need to retrieve the `offsetWidth` and not the `width`:

```
<input [ngStyle]="{'width.px': myTable.offsetWidth }">
<table #myTable>...</table>
```

In the above code, the table tag width will match input's width.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwnt9u)**

Comment: After looking for a way to make fixed table header and footer this saved my day

Comment: I am busting my head with angular, i did with javascript some tables with fixed header and footer , with transitions on width and a position that is bound to the scroll of the element. I am trying to do this in angular, do you have any advice? My current problem is like this. I have a header positioned absolute, i need to scroll the header left and right after the parent element scroll position, do you know any way i can do that? I presume with @hostlistener , but i don;t know how to catch the scrolling element.

Comment: @HDsSergiu, without the code and the exact context, it's hard to answer, but I as much as I understood, yes with a hostlistener. Put it on the parent and with a handle (template variable or Viewchild in typescript) get the header. Or if you put the hostlistener on the header watch for the document scroll

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `[style.width.px]`

```
<input [style.width.px]="{'width.px': myTable.offsetWidth }">
<table #myTable>...</table>
```